# Got errors, while running exe file built with pyinstaller and Google Cloud API integration in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, pyinstaller

I am working one file python project.

I integrated google-cloud-API for realtime speech streaming and recognition.

It works with `python aaa.py` command well.

Now I need windows build file(.exe), so I used pyinstaller program and I got `aaa.exe` file successfully.

But I got this error while running speech streaming by using Google cloud API.

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'D:\AI\ai\dist\AAA\google\cloud\gapic\speech\v1\speech_client_config.json'

So I copied this `speech_client_config.json` file in needed path, after that I got below error again.

> Exception  in 'grpc._cython.cygrpc.ssl_roots_override_callback'
>   ignored E0511 01:13:14.320000000  3108
>   src/core/lib/security/security_connector/security _connector.cc:1170]
>   assertion failed: pem_root_certs != nullptr

Then, I can not find solution to get working version with google-cloud API.

I am using python version 2.7.14

I need your friendly help.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks to me like a SSL credentials mistake. I think you are not being allowed to GC. Check this [code snippet](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/security/credentials/ssl/ssl_credentials.cc#L96) and this [documentation](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/structgrpc_1_1_ssl_credentials_options.html) . Please update if this solve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. If you are willing to distribute roots.pem with your executable (just search for the file - it should be buried deep within the installation directory of grpcio), I had luck fixing this by setting GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH environment variable to the full path of this roots.pem file.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2021

To anyone who is experiencing this issue. I got it working thanks to these amazing people. See the full conversation on this github issue.
Here is the [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5774)

### **Step 1**

Credits to @cbenhagen & @rising-stark on this github [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5774).

A PyInstaller hook called `hook-grpc.py` looking like this would do the trick:

Create a python file named `hook-grpc.py` with this code.

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('grpc')
```

### **Step 2**

Put the `hook-grpc.py` file in your `\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks` directory of the python environment you are running on. So basically you can find it at

`C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks`

**Note:**

1. Just change the `yourusername` and `Python37` to your
   respective username and python version you are using.
2. For [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) users it might be different. Check this [site](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/)
   to find the anaconda python environment path you are using.

### Step 3

Once you've done that you can now convert your `.py` python program to `.exe` using [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a SSL credentials mistake. I think you are not being allowed to GC. Check this [code snippet](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/security/credentials/ssl/ssl_credentials.cc#L96) and this [documentation](https://grpc.io/grpc/cpp/structgrpc_1_1_ssl_credentials_options.html).